# Releasing leased connections in PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: connection-pooling, jersey-client, apache-commons-httpclient

We're using Jersey (ver 2.22.2) to execute REST requests, and **ApacheConnectorProvider** together with **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** to manage our connections pool.

Is there a way to release manually connections from the **leased** connections list?

**PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** provides methods to close *expired* and *idle* connections, but this will close and remove connections from the **available** connections list, which is not what I'm looking for.

The reason that I want to do it is because I want to avoid connections leaking.
The developer that is using the above service should always close the connection by doing **response.readEntity()** or **response.close()**, and if he forgets to do it, then I don't think that manually closing the connections is a good solution.
But if the connection wasn't close because of some unexpected issue, and remaining in the *leased* list, then I want to be able to close it by myself.

The same as [Apache advising to write a daemon thread to clear expired connections](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) ("Connection eviction policy"), I want to be able to clear connections from **leased** list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Call response.close() inside finally block of your code or you can use java try-with-resources (java version > 7+) as well.

```
   try{
      ClosableHttpResposne response = .....; 
    }catch(Exception e){
       // .....
    }finally{
    response.close();
    }
```

or

```
try(ClosableHttpResposne response = .....){
}catch(Exception e){
}
```